# Making JQuery horizontal accordion close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Example: http://vincent-massaro.com/map/

Currently, the script allows you to click on a piece of the accordion to open it, but it is set to close on mouseleave. When I set the mouseleave to .click, it gets confused and doesn't know what state it is in. I want to make it so that you can click to open it, and click to close it, instead of mouseleave. The code controlling this is below, and the full script is in haccordion.js linked in the page source. If someone could help me modify this script, I would be very grateful! Thanks in advance.

```
$target.click(function(){
            haccordion.expandli(config.accordionid, this)
                    config.$lastexpanded=$(this)
  })
            if (config.collapsecurrent){ //if previous content should be contracted when expanding current
                    $target.mouseleave(function(){
                          $(this).stop().animate({width:config.paneldimensions.peekw}, config.speed)
  })
  }
```

Comment: consider to use jquery.ui accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use this

```
$('.accordion-item-header').click(function() {
    var item = $(this).parent().find('.accordion-item-body');
    item.toggleClass('open').animate({
        width:item.hasClass('open') ? 0: 100 
    }, 100).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use this? I am a JQuery newbie and don't know how to take this and make it work with the script I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean variable to represent whether the accordion is open or not and just check it on click. (You'll need to toggle the variable's state on click too)

Edit:

Ok try this. Set a boolean global variable (outside the click event) like this:

```
var accordion_expanded = false;
```

Then within your click event do something like this: (I haven't tested this so you might have to massage it a bit to fit your circumstance)

In the function where you expand your accordion put this:

```
accordion_expanded = true;
```

And in the function where you contract your accordion do a

```
if(accordion_expanded == true){
   //Contract accordion code goes here

   accordion_expanded == false;
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, I am a javascript/JQuery beginner and have no idea how to write code to do that. Any suggestions or code examples?